# Mailu(docker-compose mail server). Настройка nginx reverse proxy

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, email

Всем доброго времени суток!
Настраивал обратный прокси для **mailu** (https://mailu.io/1.9/), возник банальный и тупой вопрос, как сконфигурировать параметр:

REAL_IP_FROM=x.x.x.x,y.y.y.y.y
#x.x.x.x,y.y.y.y.y is the static IP address your reverse proxy uses for connecting to Mailu.

Пробовал написать туда IP машины на которой всё крутится, но не помогло, всё так же получаю 404 ошибку.

Comment: А что это за сервер-то?

Comment: https://mailu.io/1.9/
Запускается этот стек на Ubuntu 20.04